# VAR Model in R, Error in Solve.default(sigma)

Tags: r, variables, var

I'm currently trying to fit a VAR model with 6 variables from an XTS time series set. I have over 800 observations as well. The code I'm trying to run is

```
estim <- VAR(MinuteSeries, p = AIC , type = "both") 
summary(estim)
```

The value AIC is the AIC value retrieved from the lag-select function. When I pass the summary statement I am given the error:

```
Error in solve.default(Sigma) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 5.61898e-17
```

I have read online that this can be due to have a larger amount of coefficients in the model than observations in the data, however I have over 800 observations in the data and still getting this issue with just 6 variables. Is the size the issue still for my model or am I missing something more important?

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same issue with seemingly non-problematic data (60 observations with 4 variable TS). So, I read online that one guy advised the following:

"It isn't just the high correlation of your variables, but also their scaling with respect to the response and/or the spatial coefficient. Using a different method= (say "LU") and using a power trace vector trs= may get you there too, but re-scaling the variable will also re-scale its square. The same problem affects the STSLS - re-scale the variable. If these are say in Euro, use thousand, million or whatever Euro instead, for example."

It helped when I transformed GDP from $ to billions $.